# How do I use oom_score_adj?

Tags: process, memory-usage

On 11.04, `/proc/[pid]` contains `oom_score_adj`, but `man proc` describes the old `oom_adj`. I have googled unsuccessfully for any information on how to use this.

What I need to arrange is that processes started by 'pbs' or 'gridengine' are killed before anything else gets killed. How can I do that?

Comment: To have this change permanently for services managed by Upstart: [How to set OOM killer adjustments for daemons permanently?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62022/23363).

Comment: It's already an answer. It links to it. :)

Comment: But not on this site :-)

Comment: I know the answer is already giving by @fredericNord with choom cmd. I usually do the `echo <new-oom-adj-value > /proc/<pid>/oom_score_adj` method but looking for an API to call.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<sup>Based on [my own Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62022/23363) on Unix&Linux on a similar question.</sup>

As Stuart pointed out very well in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/249992/88802), valid values are integers in the range of -1000 to 1000 for `oom_score_adj`. The *lower* the value, the *lower* the chance that it's going to be killed.

It's very inconvenient to have to change this value over and over again once you restart the application. The information is simply lost after the process has terminated. Upstart (the init daemon in Ubuntu til 2014, then moved to systemd), has a nice option for this to configure for daemons to make sure it's set whenever it has (re)started:

> [`oom score`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#oom-score)
>
> [...] snip [...]
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> # this application is a "resource hog"
> oom score 1000
>
> expect daemon
> respawn
> exec /usr/bin/leaky-app
> ```

So, basically, you can edit the `/etc/init/myservice.conf` configuration file for the services you like to change, to include a line `oom score -1000`. I do assume that the services 'pbs' or 'gridengine' you're talking about in your question is Upstart-enabled, otherwise you'll need another way to change this permanently.

Answer (score 13):

If you can modify the start script spawning the process that you want to prioritize for oom-killer, add the following to the start script:

```
echo 1000 > /proc/self/oom_score_adj
```

The value is inherited for child processes.

Answer (score 12):

We have [choom](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/8fa223daba1963c34cc828075ce6773ff01fafe3) now, from [util-linux](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/util-linux) (*display and adjust OOM-killer score*):

```
choom --adjust -100 myprogram
```

The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/choom.1.html) has more information.

Comment: Wow, this is a well kept secret!

Answer (score 9):

If you set a high(ish) value for either oom_adj or oom_score_adj then they will be killed first. e.g.

```
echo 15 > /proc/[pid]/oom_adj
```

oom_adj goes from -16 to 15 and as mentioned above oom_score_adj accepts -1000 to 1000

Comment: You need to be root to do this. `sudo sh -c "echo -1000 > /proc/[PID]/oom_score_adj"`

Comment: Actually, you can *increase* the score for *your* processes w/o root ("yeah, this can be oom-killed"). Decreasing (below 0) needs root.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question. With **systemd** in recent systems it couldn't be easier.

As you prefer, `export EDITOR=vim` or whatnot, then:

```
systemctl edit mysql.service
```

and input the two drop-in lines:

```
[Service]
OOMScoreAdjust=-150
```

save & exit; done — permanently.

---

Use `systemctl edit --full` if you're confused by the concept of [config drop-in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services) (just be careful to avoid writing to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/*.service` as your edits will get destroyed on updates).

---

Doc: [`man systemd.exec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)

> OOMScoreAdjust=
>
> Sets the adjustment level for the Out-Of-Memory killer for executed processes. Takes an integer between -1000 (to disable OOM killing for this process) and 1000 (to make killing of this process under memory pressure very likely). See proc.txt[1] for details.

Answer (score 6):

Looking into the code is always a good idea. Normally I use the search function of kernel.org, but its currently down. Github does a good job too. I found this:

> Instead, a new tunable,
>   /proc/pid/oom_score_adj, is added that ranges from -1000 to +1000.  It may
>   be used to polarize the heuristic such that certain tasks are never
>   considered for oom kill while others may always be considered.  The value
>   is added directly into the badness() score so a value of -500, for
>   example, means to discount 50% of its memory consumption in comparison to
>   other tasks either on the system, bound to the mempolicy, in the cpuset,
>   or sharing the same memory controller.

From https://github.com/mirrors/linux-2.6/commit/a63d83f427fbce97a6cea0db2e64b0eb8435cd10#include/linux/oom.h

Comment: THanks for the pointer, but I'm hoping someone will drive by and shoot in a recipe for the whole problem, which would seem to be arranging for this value to be set for the exec daemon of pbs before it forks any jobs.

Answer (score 2):

The files `/proc/<pid>/oom_adj` and `/proc/<pid>/oom_score_adj` adjust the same setting in the kernel and you can modify either one. The difference is that the older interface `oom_adj` uses more coarse scale from `-16` to `15` whereas newer `oom_score_adj` uses scale from `-1000` to `1000`.

You can verify that both files control the same setting like this (in shell):

```
$ cd /proc/$$
$ grep . oom_*
oom_adj:0
oom_score:0
oom_score_adj:0
$ echo 500 > oom_score_adj
$ grep . oom_*
oom_adj:8
oom_score:500
oom_score_adj:500
$ echo 10 > oom_adj
$ grep . oom_*
oom_adj:9
oom_score:588
oom_score_adj:588
```

I used Linux kernel version 5.4.119 which seems to have off-by-one behavior for the older interface. I'm not sure if this intentional or not. The read-only file `oom_score` returns the actually used value which should be identical to `oom_score_adj`.

Setting negative values for either file requires root access so this can be used only to volunteer to be killed in case of system running out of memory (OOM).

The way `oom_score` works is checking the actual memory usage of a process and then counting `1000 * memory_usage_of_process / total_usable_memory_in_system + oom_score` to get a comparision number for every process. The higher the number you get, the more probable its for OOM Killer to select the given process (in addition to memory usage, the amount of child processes are considered, too). The value of `-1000` for `oom_score` is special because it cannot be selected by OOM Killer no matter the computed value of the above computation. In most cases the resulting value would be negative enough to not be selected in any case.

And you can use either of these to volunteer your shell (script or not) as the volunteer for killing in case system runs out of memory. **Note that all new processes launched by a process will inherit the same `oom_score_adj` value by default so you can basically write a shell script that does**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1000 > /proc/$$/oom_score_adj
the-command-that-should-be-killed-if-oom
echo 0 > /proc/$$/oom_score_adj
```

That way only `the-command-that-should-be-killed-if-oom` (and it's subprocesses) will end up with `oom_score_adj` value 1000 and your script is still using the value 0 after the third line. You can obviously skip the last line if the script doesn't need to do anything after the process exits – in that case you should also use `exec` to save some RAM by not keeping the shell script alive after starting the process.