Ubuntu 22.04 crashes when out of memory
My Ubuntu system always crashes and resets the user log in whenever it comes close to running out of memory.
I checked the logs and I these two messages:
oom_reaper: reaped process 2558094 (brave), now anon-rss:180kB, file-rss:636kB, shmem- systemd-journald[354]: /dev/kmsg buffer overrun, some messages lost.

org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.

The oom_reaper only logs the termination of brave, but a following log shows the gnome shell has been terminated, which may cause the full reset.
Can Brave be the culprit here? Or am I not looking at this correctly.
EDIT: I cannot seem to reproduce the crash by opening 100+ tabs, full trace of the invocation:
Apr 15 16:43:39 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813819] pulseaudio invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x140cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_COMP), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813828] CPU: 15 PID: 2623891 Comm: pulseaudio Tainted: G           O       6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813832] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. Zenbook UM5401QA_UM5401QA/UM5401QA, BIOS UM5401QA_UM5401QA.300 09/10/2021
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813834] Call Trace:
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813836]  <TASK>
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813841]  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813848]  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813851]  dump_header+0x50/0x290
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813856]  oom_kill_process+0x10d/0x1c0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813860]  out_of_memory+0x103/0x350
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813863]  __alloc_pages_may_oom+0x112/0x1e0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813869]  __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0x46f/0x9a0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813874]  __alloc_pages+0x31d/0x350
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813879]  alloc_pages+0x91/0x1a0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813883]  folio_alloc+0x1d/0x60
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813887]  filemap_alloc_folio+0x31/0x40
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813891]  __filemap_get_folio+0xd8/0x230
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813895]  filemap_fault+0x454/0x750
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813898]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813905]  __do_fault+0x39/0x150
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813910]  do_read_fault+0x11d/0x170
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813914]  do_fault+0xf3/0x170
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813918]  handle_pte_fault+0x74/0x170
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813921]  __handle_mm_fault+0x65c/0x720
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813927]  handle_mm_fault+0x164/0x360
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813930]  do_user_addr_fault+0x212/0x6b0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813934]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813938]  exc_page_fault+0x83/0x1b0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813943]  asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813948] RIP: 0033:0x713644238b30
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813989] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at 0x713644238b06.
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813991] RSP: 002b:00007ffc298baec8 EFLAGS: 00010246
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813994] RAX: 0000000000000029 RBX: 000061b39f184ce0 RCX: 0000000000000001
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813996] RDX: 0000000000000029 RSI: 000061b39f0dcf20 RDI: 000061b39f16b3a0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.813998] RBP: 000061b39f16b3a0 R08: 000061b39f184ce0 R09: 0000000000000029
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814000] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000000000
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814001] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 000061b39ee1f5e8
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814007]  </TASK>
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814009] Mem-Info:
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814011] active_anon:1607856 inactive_anon:1206507 isolated_anon:0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814011]  active_file:0 inactive_file:319 isolated_file:0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814011]  unevictable:153277 dirty:19 writeback:0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814011]  slab_reclaimable:145240 slab_unreclaimable:210891
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814011]  mapped:131197 shmem:352061 pagetables:99782
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814011]  sec_pagetables:0 bounce:0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814011]  kernel_misc_reclaimable:0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814011]  free:32858 free_pcp:42 free_cma:0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814017] Node 0 active_anon:6431424kB inactive_anon:4826028kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:1276kB unevictable:613108kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:524788kB dirty:76kB writeback:0kB shmem:1408244kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 90112kB writeback_tmp:0kB kernel_stack:144528kB pagetables:399128kB sec_pagetables:0kB all_unreclaimable? no
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814023] Node 0 DMA free:13312kB boost:0kB min:64kB low:80kB high:96kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15996kB managed:15360kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814030] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2857 15291 15291 15291
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814037] Node 0 DMA32 free:64360kB boost:2048kB min:14664kB low:17816kB high:20968kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:525340kB inactive_anon:1225660kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:4628kB writepending:4kB present:3060756kB managed:2994812kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814043] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 12433 12433 12433
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814049] Node 0 Normal free:53760kB boost:0kB min:54900kB low:68624kB high:82348kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:5906504kB inactive_anon:3599948kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:1376kB unevictable:608480kB writepending:72kB present:13077504kB managed:12740348kB mlocked:100kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:168kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814056] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814062] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 2*2048kB (UM) 2*4096kB (M) = 13312kB
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814080] Node 0 DMA32: 403*4kB (UME) 1299*8kB (UME) 690*16kB (UME) 337*32kB (UME) 241*64kB (UME) 107*128kB (UME) 8*256kB (UM) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 64996kB
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814102] Node 0 Normal: 1112*4kB (UME) 1401*8kB (UME) 951*16kB (UME) 441*32kB (UME) 99*64kB (UME) 22*128kB (UME) 10*256kB (UM) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 56696kB
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814123] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814126] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814128] 375985 total pagecache pages
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814129] 21758 pages in swap cache
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814130] Free swap  = 20kB
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814131] Total swap = 2097148kB
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814133] 4038564 pages RAM
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814134] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814135] 100934 pages reserved
Apr 15 16:43:40 zenbook-jeroen kernel: [370346.814136] 0 pages hwpoisoned


I'm not clear on what you're asking, do you need help in understanding what's making it run out of memory? I mean for the system to misbehave / crash under low memory conditions it's kind of expected. Do you swap to a file / partition?

I have a 2GB swap file.
I am not 100% what the issue is but it doesn't seem right. ~once a day my labtop completely crashes and resets the user when out of memory. For example, when I am in a zoom call, it has crashed when I open a tab in my browser.
I do not expect to solve freezing and crashing when low on memory, but it would be nice if it would not be so harsh, with 16GB of RAM a complete meltdown during office work seems off.
I actually think there is some kind of memory leak when doing programming work in VSCode or PGAdmin which makes the OOM issue more severe.

I use VSCode too, sometimes on a fairly modern (although it's a NUC) machine; I sometimes have to shut it down and reopen it, it's incredibliy memory hungry and possibly a factor leading to your issues. Well the thing is the OOM decides on its own what to kill, all you can do is change the OOM score to lessen the likelyhood of killing the process you don't want it to: https://askubuntu.com/q/60672/380067 . I would try this and expand swap space at the same time to mitigate the error, nonetheless to update the system (if doable) to see if potential leaks get resolved with the update.
